# What is wrong with this query, and how can I make it more efficient?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a `ProjectNum column` that contains a `string data type`. Normally the numbers are `X1234...` but if there is no number assigned, then one must be autogenerated and depending on the priority assigned to the project depends whether it begins with `C or F`. So an autogenerated number must begin with `C or F` and be followed by six digits and also auto-increment. So here is my query...

```
SELECT MAX(CINT(RIGHT(ProjectNum, 6))) AS LastDigits
FROM project_master_query
WHERE ((ProjectNum LIKE (IIF([@priorityDefID] = 4, "C*", "F*"))));
```

This allows me to grab the last auto-incremented number and then I can autogenerate a number in code by adding 1. The issue is, when I send in `@priorityDefID of 4` (and at the moment there are none in the database that begin with "C"), I receive the error `"This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated.` For example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements. Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables."

Not quite sure why this comes up with I pass 4, but a 1, 2 or 3 work fine and return the correct value. I was thinking of instead of writing `MAX`, just grabbing all of them that begin with C or F and then grab the right 6 digits, order by descending and grabbing the top 1?

Comment: I would try to avoid having to use a query that looks like this. I don't think it's wise to have logic contained inside your ProjectNum that causes you to need these kinds of queries/functions. What if the priority for the project changes, do you change the ProjectNum? Use incrementing numbers for the ProjectNum and then use a Priority column.

Comment: It seems `project_master_query` may be a query instead of a table.  If so, how is `ProjectNum` stored in the query's source table(s)?  As @HK1 mentioned, combining *two facts* (priority and sequence number) in one field is not the best design ... and it makes this query more challenging.  Consider whether you can possibly change the table design to "one field, one fact".  Whenever you need to see them combined, use a query expression: `SELECT priority & sequence_number AS ProjectNum`

Comment: @HK1 That's a good point, but unfortunately I don't make the rules. But judging the way they set these things up, they won't change. Priority 1, 2, and 3 are F type projects and 4 is a C type which is a totally different type of project and I don't believe would ever change.

Answer (score 1):

That query has numerous issues and I'm not really clear about what all is going on so I don't know where to start.  However I can warn you about a danger of using `CInt()` with 6 digits.  `CInt("999999")` throws an overflow error because the maximum *integer* value is 32,767.  You would be safer to use `CLng` because the maximum long integer value is 2,147,483,647 ... so a long integer will accommodate all possible 6 digit values.

Although that issue may not be a source of trouble with the present `ProjectNum` values, it's something which may bite you in the future as you store more `ProjectNum` values.

Regarding *"[the error message] comes up with I pass 4, but a 1, 2 or 3 work fine and return the correct value"*, you also said *"at the moment there are none in the database that begin with 'C'"*.  That means the query returns no rows in that situation.  I suspect that would cause a problem with  `RIGHT(ProjectNum, 6)` because `Right(Null, 6)` triggers an *invalid use of Null* error.

Check whether the error goes away after you add a row with a `ProjectNum` which begins with *"C"*.

Comment: Good point with the INT value. I haven't checked whether it does yet or not if a ProjectNum begins with "C" but I figured I'd get nothing returned so my datatable would come back with no rows and I could proceed to generate "C000001". But your answer makes sense since there is no ProjectNum assigned yet.

Comment: Actually, I don't see how casting your substring to any type of number adds any value.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't, but I didn't think you could perform a MAX on a string value.